# Dspace thumbnails on "recently added" bootstrap carousel

Tags: thumbnails, dspace

I would like to know how to request thumbnails of each item to be showed in the recently added bootstrap carousel.
I'm using DSPACE 6.0, JSP interface.
All thumbnails are already enabled and they are listed correctly on the "browse by " results.